# Spring Custom Annotation Solver MulitpartFile Resolves to Null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot, annotations

I have a Spring custom annotation which I am using instead of `@requestParam`

```
public Response uploadImages(@myResolver(value = "imageFile", required = true) final MultipartFile multiPartFile) {...}
```

However, the mulitpart file parameter is resolved to null. So I put a breakpoint in my HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument to see if the argument was being resolved, but the breakpoint is never reached. But I know my custom annotation works for other params such as String, long e.t.c.

When I try using `@requestParam` instead it works fine, and the multipart file is resolved.

```
public Response uploadImages(@requestParam(value = "imageFile", required = true) final MultipartFile multiPartFile) {...}
```

Does anyone know why mulitpart file is being resolved to null using my custom parameter resolver and not using resolveArgument and how I could solve this please?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The config for adding argument resolvers

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
  super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
  argumentResolvers.add(new MyAnnotationResolver());
}
```

My annotation definition

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Component
public @interface MyResolver{

  String value() default "";
  boolean required() default true;
  String defaultValue() default ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE;
  String errorCode() default "40000";
```

Comment: show us your custom annotation definition along with relevant configurations

Comment: What is the reason for your custom annotation? You basically replaced all nice features of Spring with your own single annotation. You might want to check the handler for `@RequestParam` and how `MultipartFile` is handled there.

Comment: I'm using my custom annotation to throw my own exceptions using my error response template rather than spring throwing it's own exception when there is a missing parameter

Comment: If that is the only thing you want, create an exception converter instead of replacing all the binding and converting spring does for you.